# How can I set different color for light and dark Chakra-UI themes?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am using the Chakra-UI theme and going to customize the light and dark themes' colors.
I don't know the way of about set different colors for light and dark themes.
For example, I am going to set different color values for light and dark themes, like below.

```
import { extendTheme, ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react"

const lightThemeColor = {
  gray: {
    500: '#828288',
    800: '#171822',
  }
}

const darkThemeColor = {
  gray: {
    500: '#75B046',
    800: '#1E1F2B',
  }
}

const theme = extendTheme({
  lightTheme: lightThemeColor,  // <== unfortunately, there isn't lightTheme key for setting light Theme.
  darkTheme: darkThemeColor
})

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

I don't know how to set light theme and dark theme color.
How can I set the light and dark theme colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Wen can use [chakra semantic token](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/semantic-tokens). I have a helper function that help generate semantic token from a list of colors as follow:

```html
import {
    ChakraProvider,
    cookieStorageManagerSSR,
    localStorageManager,
    extendTheme,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { mode } from '@chakra-ui/theme-tools';

export const lightTheme = {
    primary: {
        300: '#ECEDF0',
        400: '#FDFDFF',
    },
    secondary: {
        300: '#646464',
        400: '#424242',
    },
    brand: {
        300: '#7C82FB',
        400: '#5F63FC',
    },
};

export const darkTheme = {
    primary: {
        300: '#646464',
        400: '#424242',
    },
    secondary: {
        300: '#ECEDF0',
        400: '#FDFDFF',
    },
    brand: {
        300: '#94d3ac',
        400: '#29c7ac',
    },
};

const theme = extendTheme({
    semanticTokens: {
        colors: getColorsFromTheme(lightTheme, darkTheme),
    },
    styles: {
        global: (props) => ({
            'html, body': {
                // ...
            },
            body: {
                backgroundColor: mode(
                    lightTheme.primary[400],
                    darkTheme.primary[400],
                )(props),
            },
        }),
    },
});

/**
 * make it work in NextJS
 *
 * @see https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/color-mode#add-colormodemanager-optional-for-ssr
 */
const Chakra = ({ cookies, children }) => {
    const colorModeManager =
        typeof cookies === 'string'
            ? cookieStorageManagerSSR(cookies)
            : localStorageManager;

    return (
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme} colorModeManager={colorModeManager}>
            {children}
        </ChakraProvider>
    );
};

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    return (
        <Chakra cookies={pageProps.cookies}>
            <AudioPlayerProvider>
                <Layout {...pageProps}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>
            </AudioPlayerProvider>
        </Chakra>
    );
};
```

**Old answer**

For chakra **V2**, we can use css variables in `global` object (which give us access to `colorMode`). Attention, `colors` object is still necessary for ChakraUI to interpret css variables, however the real colors:

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { mode } from '@chakra-ui/theme-tools';

const theme = extendTheme({
styles: {
    global: (props) => ({
        body: {
            bg: mode('#FDFDFF', '#212121')(props),
        },
        ':root': {
            '--chakra-colors-primary-400': mode(
                '#7C82FB',
                '#94d3ac',
            )(props),
            '--chakra-colors-primary-500': mode(
                '#5F63FC',
                '#29c7ac',
            )(props),
        },
    }),
},
// colors object is declared so chakra interprets it as css variables
// however real colors is defined in ':root' with darkmode conditions
colors: {
    primary: {
        400: '#7C82FB',
        500: '#5F63FC',
    },
    success: {
        500: '#21bf73',
    },
    danger: {
        500: '#FA4243',
    },
},
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This mightbe helpful for your problme.
https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/features/color-mode

```
export default class Document extends NextDocument {  render() {
return (
  <Html lang='en'>
    <Head />
    <body>
      {/*  Here's the script */}
      <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode} />
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
)
```

}
}

create global state for managing initialColorMode and change its value.